# Trim all but 2 characters after comma in for each in ASP.NET MVC Api call C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, api, foreach, asp.net-apicontroller

In my for each loop, I am needing to trim the full name being returned in my stored procedure. I would need the "last name, first 2 characters of first name" but trim everything else.

```
foreach (var mrnRecord in mrnRecords)
{
    var filtered = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<string>("MRN").Contains(mrnRecord));

    patient = new Patient();
    orders = new List<Order>();

    patient.MRN = filtered.First().Field<string>("MRN");
    patient.CurrentLocation = filtered.First().Field<string>("CurrentLocation") + "<br />" + filtered.First().Field<string>("PatientName") + "<br />" + filtered.First().Field<string>("Isolation");
    patient.PatientName = filtered.First().Field<string>("PatientName");
    patient.PatientType = filtered.First().Field<string>("PatientType");
    patient.VisitId = filtered.First().Field<string>("VisitID");
```

Comment: does PatientName have the first, last, and middle names separated by a space?

Comment: PatientName is lastname, firstname middlename if applicable. Last name and first name are comma separated. First and middle names are spaces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the name comes through as "First Middle Last", you could use

```
var myString = "Franklin Delano Roosevelt";
var stringArr = myString.Split(' ');
var lastFirstTwoInitials = stringArr[2] + ", " + stringArr[0].Substring(0, 2);
```

EDIT: Just saw your comment about format being "Last, First Middle"

```
var stringArr = patient.PatientName.Split(' ');
var lastFirstTwoInitials = stringArr[0] +  " " + stringArr[1].Substring(0, 2);
```

or

```
var stringArr = patient.PatientName.Split(' ');
var lastFirstTwoInitials = patient.PatientName.Substring(0, stringArr[0].Length + 3);
```

Comment: so in var myString, woud that be where I would put "patient.PatientName" since this is the only field I am trimming

Comment: Yes, that would be patientName. I was just using that name as filler

Comment: so I added the syntax but I believe I have it to where the dt is not populating in time. here is my error: System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Respiratory.Models.Patient.PatientName.get returned null.

Comment: I can't really tell what's going on without looking at your code, but it sounds like you're not initializing patient.PatientName before parsing it. I'd recommend making sure that line
`patient.PatientName = filtered.First().Field<string>("PatientName");` is still being called before parsing or simply replacing all instances of `patient.PatientName` in my code with `filtered.First().Field<string>("PatientName");`
But like I said, I can't tell without seeing your code.